# ¿Cómo mostrar los iconos de un action Column de EXTJS dinamicamente en un evento focus?

Tags: extjs

Tengo un `treePanel` al cual le quiero agregar un `actionColumn` pero el cual quiero que solo se vea conforme el cursor pasa por alguno de los elementos, alguien que me pueda dar un ejemplo o donde puedo conseguir la info de como hacerlo, estoy en extjs 6.

codigo:

```
     {  
            xtype:'treepanel',  
            id: 'grdCoverage',  
            //plugins: [{  
            //    ptype: 'treefilter'  
            //    , allowParentFolders: true  
            //}],  
            width: '100%',  
            autoScroll: false,  
            store: 'catCoverage',  
            forceFit:true,  
            height: 400,  
            rootVisible: false,  
            hideHeaders:true,  
            viewConfig: {  
                autoScroll: true,  
                loadMask: false  
            },  
            columns: [  
                {  
                xtype: 'treecolumn',  
                dataIndex: 'description_element',  
                flex: 1,  
                text: 'Cobertura'  
                },  
            ],  
   }
```

Comment: Debes agregar el código que estás usando actualmente, de otra manera tu pregunta podría ser cerrada por no cumplir con las políticas de calidad del sitio. Te recomiendo que leas el tema [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y en general el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help).